# How can I insert an interceptor with AngularJS to redirect to login page?

Tags: session, angularjs

I have a login system that will hold the session for 2 hours. After 2 hours, when the client makes API calls, they get back an error:

```
{
  "Success": false,
  "Error": {
    "ErrorCode": "002",
    "ErrorMessage": "Session expired"
  }
}
```

I need to then redirect the client to `/login` when that happens. The problem is that I get that error from individual API calls, so rather than change EVERY API call, is it possible to have a global interceptor?

Comment: You can add an http interceptor, inspect the answer and redirect to login according to the error code. What version of angular do you use because the API changed a bit in the last version. Another question : What http status do you get when you're in error ? 200 or 4xx ? (It will determine if you need to put your interceptor on success or error hanlder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the example for `Interceptors` found [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ng.%24http), you can do something like the following in the `response` section of the interceptor:

```
response: function(resp){
    // resp.data will contain your response object from the server
    if(resp.data && !resp.data.Success){
        // check for error code
        if(resp.data.Error && resp.data.ErrorCode === '002'){
            $location.path('/login');
            return $q.reject(resp);
        }
    }
    return resp || $q.when(resp);
},
```

This is assuming that your server is returning a `200` when you get this error message, not on a `401` or `403`, but that's what it looks like you're doing.  Hope that helps.